# what should the equivalent Mule4 configuration for this quartz:connector and in Mule4?

Tags: java, mule, anypoint-studio, mule4

I am migrating Mule 3 application to Mule4,From Mule-config.xml we are calling synchronized method . Below is the Mule3-config.xml looks like :-

```
<quartz:connector name="quartzConnector" createMultipleTransactedReceivers="false" numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="1" >
    <dispatcher-threading-profile doThreading="false"/>
</quartz:connector>


<flow name="rccHeartbeatTask">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="quartzConnector" repeatInterval="1000" startDelay="60000" jobName="rccHeartbeat">
        <quartz:event-generator-job/>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    
    <component>
        <method-entry-point-resolver>
            <include-entry-point method="process"/>
        </method-entry-point-resolver>
    
        <singleton-object class="com.emsgt.occ600.task.RCCHeartbeatGenerator"/>
    </component>
</flow>
```

process method looks like below :-

```
public synchronized void process() throws Exception {   
    //some code
}
```

I want to convert this to Mule 4 and my converted Mule-config. xml looks like below :-

```
<spring:config name="springConfig" files="beans.xml" /> 
<flow name="mule-configFlow" doc:id="c7374765-8867-4e12-b62b-88e69f98824c" >
        <scheduler doc:name="rccHeartbeat" doc:id="85e2d9b9-330d-48a1-a37b-4882a46bcaa6" >
            <scheduling-strategy >
                <fixed-frequency startDelay="60000" frequency="1000"/>
            </scheduling-strategy>
        </scheduler>
         <java:invoke instance="taskScheduler" class="com.emsgt.occ600.task.RCCHeartbeatGenerator" method="process()" />
    </flow>
```

beans.xml looks like below:-

```
<bean id="taskScheduler" scope="singleton" class="com.emsgt.occ600.task.RCCHeartbeatGenerator">
        </bean>
```

If I build this converted application, build and deployment is successful but I am getting below error after deployment:-

```
Error stacktrace :
Message               : Invocation of Method 'process()' from Class 'com.emsgt.occ600.task.RCCHeartbeatGenerator' without any argument resulted in an error.
Cause: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - com/emssatcom/dal/util/CacheRecord
Element               : mule-configFlow/processors/0 @ occtaskscheduler-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-mule-application:mule-config.xml:31
Element DSL           : <java:invoke instance="taskScheduler" class="com.emsgt.occ600.task.RCCHeartbeatGenerator" method="process()"></java:invoke>
Error type            : JAVA:INVOCATION
FlowStack             : at mule-configFlow(mule-configFlow/processors/0 @ occtaskscheduler-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-mule-application:mule-config.xml:31)
```

In place of "process method" if I call any non synchronized method, application runs without errors.

Below lines are missing in my migrated mule-config.xml.

<quartz:connector name="quartzConnector" createMultipleTransactedReceivers="false" numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="1" >

</quartz:connector>

what should the equivalent Mule4 configuration for this quartz:connector and  in Mule4?
Please add if anything else is missing in migrated xml.

Definition of beans.xml looks like below :-

[beans.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l7ey.png)

Comment: This is two questions in one. Please separate the quartz question into a separate one.

Comment: Please share the bean definition in spring.xml. Why are you using a bean in Mule 4 if you are not using it in Mule 3? Are there any more lines to the error message? Please share.

Comment: Using beans.xml, to define the method as singleton in mule4

Comment: Attaching the error stack and beans.xml in description above

Comment: Please follow Stackoverflow guidelines and add beans.xml as text in the question. Avoid using links and screenshots (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).
Is the Java class in a Java source in the same project or is it in a library? Have you tried removing the synchronized keyword to see if it works?
Remember to create a separate question for Quartz. That's a separate topic unrelated to the error you are having.